# What is the appropriate approach for implementing custom DependencyProperty for two-way binding in a UserControl?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

I was trying to implement a UserControl called `ParityTypeSelect` that contains two RadioButton - `Odd` & `Even`, and the UserControl is to have a DependencyProperty called `ParityType` which is going to be used in a Two-Way binding. The idea is simple - if `Odd` is selected `ParityType` should return 1, and if `Even` is selected `ParityType` should return 0.
Here's the code -

XAML (UserControl):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <RadioButton Name="rdoOdd" Content="Odd" Margin="5" Checked="rdoOdd_CheckedChnaged" Unchecked="rdoOdd_CheckedChnaged" />
    <RadioButton Name="rdoEven" Content="Even" Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code-Behind (UserControl):

```
public partial class ParityTypeSelect : UserControl
{
    //Some Code

    static ParityTypeSelect()
    {
        FrameworkPropertyMetadata parityTypeMetaData =
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnParityTypeChanged),
                                          new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceParityTypeValue));
        ParityTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ParityType", typeof(int?), typeof(ParityTypeSelect),
                                                         parityTypeMetaData,
                                                         new ValidateValueCallback(ValidateParityTypeValue));
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ParityTypeProperty;
    public int? ParityType
    {
        get { return (int?)GetValue(ParityTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ParityTypeProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnParityTypeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ParityTypeSelect select = (ParityTypeSelect)d;
        int? newValue = (int?)e.NewValue;

        if (newValue != null && newValue <= 1)
        {
            if (newValue == 1)
                select.rdoOdd.IsChecked = true;
            else
                select.rdoEven.IsChecked = true;
        }
        else
            return;
    }

    private void rdoOdd_CheckedChnaged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)sender;
        if (radioButton.IsChecked != null)
        {
            if (radioButton.IsChecked.Value)
                SetValue(ParityTypeProperty, 1);
            else
                SetValue(ParityTypeProperty, 0);
        }
    }

    //Some more Code
}
```

XAML (Consumer):

```
<StackPanel>
     <aucl:ParityTypeSelect ParityType="{Binding Path=Format.FisrtBitType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>                
</StackPanel>
```

...And it's working. BUT the thing is, this was my first implementation of DependencyProperty. So I'm a bit concerned if I'm doing it right. Am I using the `OnParityTypeChanged` method in a right way? Is the use of `rdoOdd_CheckedChnaged` event handler to set the proerty value OK? Is there any better or more appropriate way to doing any of this whole implementation? I always look forward for quality coding. So any suggestion, improvement-recommendations, comments from `WPF` guys will be thankfully appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to write this in comments but I will do it as a seprate answer. I would bind the property instead of doing it in code behind. You will need a converter because int? will need to be converted to bool. To make the converter as generic as possible I would use an `EqualityConverter` which you could bind like this:

```
<RadioButton Content="Odd" Margin="5" IsChecked="{Binding ParityTypeSelect,Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource equalityConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" />
```

Code for the converter is here:

```
public class EqualityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object TrueValue { get; set; }
    public object FalseValue { get; set; }

    public EqualityConverter()
    {
        //default the TrueValue and FalseValue to true and false.
        //this way we can easily use the same converter for simple comparison or as an IIF statement
        TrueValue = true;
        FalseValue = false;
    }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null && parameter == null) return TrueValue;
        if (value == null && parameter != null) return FalseValue;

        //in some cases we might need to compare an enum value to an integer.
        //this will fail unless we specifically convert them
        if (value is int && parameter is Enum)
            parameter = System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter);
        else if (value is Enum && parameter is int)
            value = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);

        return value.Equals(parameter) ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null && TrueValue == null) return true;
        if (value == null && FalseValue == null) return false;
        if (value.Equals(TrueValue)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

A few other things I would say:
- instead of using a usercontrol you are better off inheriting from Control (just as a standard class, no xaml). You then put the xaml into a file called Generic.xaml. There is little bit of stuff involved so you would need to search the details
- you have unecessary calls to CoerceParityTypeValue and ValidateParityTypeValue, you can leave these out.
- when defining dependency props just type "propdp" (without quotes) and push tab
- usually controls on controls are named starting with PART_, eg PART_OddButton

EDIT: Here is an article which appears to show the main points but isn't quite complete:
http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html

Comment: thanks for that "prpodp" magic - didn't know something like that existed, though it gives a `UIPropertyMetadata`, not a `FrameworkPropertyMetadata`. and i got that you are suggesting a `CustomControl` instead of `UserControl`. what i don't understand is what are the advantages of an `IValueConverter` to replace 5/6 lines of code. isn't it right that the `SomeProperty="{Binding... ...}"` syntax always generates an event handler behind the scene?

Comment: There are a lot of similar snippets to propdp such as "cw", "ctor" etc. If you need FrameworkPropertyMetadata then you can just change it. The advantage is that someone can replace the interface to your control and make it whatever they like, eg red/green buttons. Because the logic is in xaml this can be done. I've also found using the events to be difficult when things get more complicated with timing issues during load. With regards the event handler behind the scenes I would say that is likely. It needs to tap into the changes somehow.

Answer (score 0):

But one thing could be better  and that is rather than setting the value of radio button in changed events code you can bind them in xaml like

```
<RadioButton Name="rdoOdd" Content="Odd" Margin="5" IsChecked="{Binding ParityTypeSelect,Mode=TwoWay,Converter=StaticResource booltoNullIntConverter }" />
```

booltoNullIntConverter  is a converter that changes bool to null int according to your requirement. I hope this will help.

Comment: The value of ParityType is an int? not a bool

Comment: I think it's just back to front, it should be a nullint to bool converter. Although I would think an equality converter would be better with a param passed in with the value.

Comment: @Nero the 'newvalue' is passed into the converter as the first parameter. You can pass in addition parameters using the ConverterParameter. I would just write an 'EqualityConverted' and pass the values in as the ConverterParameter